# Rust ownership via reference?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm in the process of learning Rust, and there's some functionality around ownership and references that consistently stumps me:

```rust
struct ThingOne {
    value: u32
}

// Assume I can't change this signature to simply own thing_ref.  Maybe
// it's from third-party code.
struct ThingTwo<'a> {
    thing_ref: &'a ThingOne
}

fn test<'a>() -> ThingTwo<'a> {
    let thing1 = ThingOne { value: 1 };

    ThingTwo { thing_ref: &thing1 }
}
```

Obviously, this can't work -- `thing1` is stack allocated, the reference can't safely escape the function.  However, this pattern seems like a common one, and I can't find a good workaround.  I could change the return type to a tuple `(ThingOne, ThingTwo)` so that the caller has moved ownership of `thing1`, but then I'd still run into issues trying to create that reference to `thing1` when initializing the `ThingTwo` result.  I could use an `Rc<ThingOne>` but that feels like a very heavy handed solution.

Is there an idiomatic way to handle this kind of code?  Or is there some other approach that's better than the way that `test()` function is structured?

Comment: I think the general rule would be "Don't make structs that hold references they don't own unless they're purely for internal use"; the author of `ThingTwo` shouldn't have written their library to depend on the caller going to the trouble of keeping the reference alive, when they could just as easily take ownership of `ThingOne` themselves, and keep the ownership setup simple. Hyper-optimizing with references gains little here, and limits flexibility for users. Not an answer because I'm just learning Rust myself, and I'm not sure my sweeping generalization accurately describes good practice.

Comment: If you're talking specifically about the case where the reference is to a value without any runtime dependencies, it can be expressed as a `const`ant instead of a variable, which will make this work. But it's unclear whether that's what you're talking about. I don't actually think that this pattern is common.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It really depends: references can be more flexible than ownership in some ways and less flexible in other ways. I think the better lesson to learn is "understand how libraries are meant to be used" (although poorly designed libraries certainly do exist). From a dummy example like this it's not possible to say whether `ThingTwo` is poorly designed or whether the user is just missing the point.